# Regular expression to match all but an ending condition

Tags: regex

I am trying to match {{anything}} using the regular expression

```
 /\{\{.*\}\}/
```

But it will not end upon the first `}}`, but on the last in the document.

```
{{anything}} {{anotherthing}}
```

will return that whole chunk, instead of two matches. How can I formulate this expression to be less greedy?

I tried to do

```
 /\{\{[^\}].*\}\}/
```

but it returned no results, same thing for

```
/\{\{.*?\}\}/
```

Bonus - to not get the curlies, but just the string, I tried

```
 /\{\{(.*)\}\}/
```

with more failure (returned empty as well). How can I also get a subset of a match?

One time my teacher told me that she could teach me regular expressions in 15 minutes. I never got that lesson, and I'm not convinced. :)

Comment: Your teacher probably meant she could teach you to swear at regex in 15 minutes.

Comment: thanks for the help guys. half my problem might have been loading the wrong file, other half, regex failure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use a non-greedy star to achieve this (adding the question mark) :

```
 /\{\{.*?\}\}/
```

You can read more on this [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html)

For the last part, matching only the string without the braces, take a look at "lookbehind" and "lookahead" [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

Answer (score 2):

If your flavor of regex does not support non-greedy `*?` (they are a novelty introduced in Perl, and not available in "classical" regex such as grep, sed, etc) you have to do something like

```
\{\{([^}]+|}[^}])*)\}\}
```

again with the caution that different regex flavors demand different backslash escapes (the `sed` in Linux, for example, would omit the backslash before the curly brackets, but requires backslash before the parentheses and alternation operator, thus `{{\([^}]\+\|}[^}])*}}` -- also note the backslash before the plus repetition operator).

So just to spell that out; literal `{{` followed by either a sequence of characters which are not closing curly bracket `[^}]` or by a literal curly bracket but something else than another literal curly bracket `}[^}]` and finally the closing literal double curly brackets `}}`.

Answer (score 1):

Use the "not" operator in the middle:

```
/\{\{[^\{\}]*\}\}/
```

I.e., inside the {{ and }} you can have anything BUT a { or }.

And if you want to capture the inside:

```
/\{\{([^\{\}]*)\}\}/
```

Comment: This fails in the case when a single curly is inside the double curlies.  It's not clear from the question whether this is an issue in reality.

Comment: This doesn't fully do what Orbit asks unfortunately, making the .* lazy would have been enough...